# How do you have multiple buttons but only one has a hoverable dropdown in html?

Tags: html, css, hover, dropdown

I have been puzzled for a while. I am making a personal website with multiple navigation buttons including one dropdown menu. The dropdown menu should be triggered when the cursor hovers over the about button. I used W3School's code as part of the foundation.
I have tried to create one myself however, when I hover over any button the menu triggers.
I played around with using  and using  but neither was successful. I tried also creating a second  but then I ran into another issue where I could not get the buttons (Gallery and Contact) to sit next to the other button (About). Below is the HTML and further is the CSS.

```
<nav class="dropdown">
<button class="about" href="about.html">About </button>
<button class="gallery" href="gallery.html">Gallery </a>
<button class="contact" href="contact.html">Contact </a>
<div class="dropdown-content"> 
    <a href="achievements.html">Achievements </a>
    <a href="education.html">Education </a>
    <a href="hobbies.html">Hobbies </a>
    <a href="career.html">Career </a>
</div>
```

```
.dropdown{
   font-size: 22px;
   font-family: "Arvo", serif;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: right;
   position:relative;
 } 
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;

 }
 /* Links inside the dropdown */
  .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;

 }.dropdown-content a:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
 }
.about:hover .dropdown-content {
     display: block;

   }
.about:hover {background-color: transparent;

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the CSS. The dropdown-content is not a child of .about so doing `.about:hover .dropdown-content` wont work. You need to use [General Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

Update it to `.about:hover ~ .dropdown-content`

**EDIT**

You also have an issue with your HTML you are opening button tags but closing a tags update them and it should work

Comment: So I changed `.about:hover .dropdown-content`  to `.about:hover ~ .dropdown-content` the dropdown menu didn't appear.

Comment: check now theres a problem with your HTML too, I have updated the answer

Comment: That fixed it however the dropdown menu does not appear under the button and the buttons in the dropdown are impossible to reach. Also the background of the menu covers the entire screen width. If its not too much from the original question how I would fix that?

Comment: UPDATE: I have fixed part of the problem. The dropdown menu now appears under the About button by changing the position from relative to absolute and adding `right: 150;` . However, its impossible to click any links inside the dropdown because it immediately goes away.

Comment: You can try updating it to `.about:hover ~ .dropdown-content, .dropdown-content:hover`

Comment: I just took the code from w3school then added to it to my website's needs to fix the problem